# How to create a specified callback function for a setState in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question might look similar to others, but it's not. The problem that I'm facing is a little bit tricky.

In the official React documentation, it says that `useEffect` can be used as an alternative for the inline `callBack` function in `setState`. To create such a `callBack` event, we need to pass an `array` on the `useEffect` function, and **only if the any of the array value changes, `useEffect` function will run**, thus creating a `callBack` function.

But suppose, in my react functional component, I had created a `state`, which contains an `object` with multiple properties.

> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({name: "john", lastName:"doe", age: 29, parent:"none", hairColor:"black"})
> ```

And two button, `button1`, `button2`. When `button1` is clicked, it triggers an `setState` function, like this:

> ```
> setState({...state, name: "steve", lastName: "potter", parent:"dead", age: 40})
> ```

and calls a `callBack` function, which is this:

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
> console.log("Name, last Name, age and parent name Changed")
> }, [state.name, state.lastName, state.parent, state.age])
> ```

And when `button2` is clicked, it also triggers a `setState`. Like this:

> `setState({...state, name: "harry", age: 19})`

and like the previous, this time also a `callBack` function happens, which is this:

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
> console.log("Name and age are changed")
> }, [state.name, state.age])
> ```

And this is the part where everything gets messy. When `button1` is clicked, I expect to get 
 a `console.log` which says `"Name, last Name, age and parent name Changed"`, but instead we get:

> ```
> "Name, last Name, age and parent name Changed"  
> "Name and age are changed"
> ```

**which indicates that both `useEffect` callBack function was triggered when `button1` is clicked.** And this is not what I wanted. The same goes for `button2`. This is happening because both `useEffect` has one **common** array value.

If it was a **React Class** based component, we would pass an inline function just after the `setState` and it was done. But in a **React Functional** component, it gets complicated. Heres the live demo on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bash-95z0w).

This type of situation happened a lot when I  trying to convert a react class based component to functional component. So how do I create a specific `callBack` function in React Functional component which runs only after that specific `setState` occurred?

Answer (score 0):

It's correct that both `useEffect`s are called. If any properties that they are dependent on change, the `useEffect` is triggered.

In your example, since both `useEffect`s are listening to `state.name`, both would trigger if this value changes.

For this approach, what you're asking is how to compare current state vs new state. `useRef` is a good use case for this.

As all your state is in one object, you can run all of this in one `useEffect` hook, and use your `state` object to trigger it:

```js
  const previousState = useRef(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (previousState.current.name !== state.name) {
      console.log("NAME CHANGED");
    }
    if (previousState.current.age !== state.age) {
      console.log("AGE CHANGED");
    }
    previousState.current = { ...state }; // Update previous state
  }, [state]);
```

I have contrived the comparisons, and it could get messy. But you can see how you can check what pieces of the state have changed and then run conditional behavior off of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is just in your expectation:

> And this is the part where everything gets messy. When button1 is clicked, I 
>        expect to get a console.log which says "Name, last Name, age and parent name Changed", but instead we get:

"Name, last Name, age and parent name Changed"
"Name and age are changed"

Off course that both effects are triggered because you have `state.name` as deppendecy in both effects - you are changing this key by clicking on each button.

Try adding a new button:

```
<button onClick={() => setState({ ...state, parent: state.parent === "live" ? "dead" : "live"})}>
        toggle parent
</button>
```

and will see that only effect which have `state.parent` as deppendency get triggered.

Does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish here are a couple possible solutions.

A `useEffect` hook will fire when any of the values you've subscribed to in the dependency array have changed. So with that in mind if we want to tell which value has been changed we can add a separate `useEffect` hook for each state value.

```
useEffect(() => console.log('Name changed.'), [state.name])
useEffect(() => console.log('Last Name changed.'), [state.lastName])
useEffect(() => console.log('Age changed.'), [state.age])
useEffect(() => console.log('Parent changed.'), [state.parent])
```

Hooks are great but not the only way to do what you're describing and in fact not always the best way. Sometimes you might want to run code specifically on button press like:

```
const onButton1Pressed = () => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    name: "steve",
    lastName: "potter",
    parent: "dead"
  }))
  console.log('Changed name, lastname, parent')
}
const onButton2Pressed = () => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    name: "harry",
    age: 19
  }))
  console.log('Changed name, age')
}
```